# AM2+ CPU on AM2 Motherboard?

Tags: cpu, upgrade, motherboard, bios

I want to perform a cheap CPU upgrade on an old Socket AM2 motherboard.  I currently have an Athlon 64 X2, and want to upgrade to a quad-core AMD Phenom.  IIUC, Socket AM2+ CPUs are backwards compatible with Socket AM2 motherboards.  However, my motherboard (an ABit KN9) does not have a BIOS upgrade available to support this and is not officially compatible with any AM2+ CPUs.

At a technical level, what does the BIOS have to do with supporting specific CPU makes/models?  What would be the likely consequences of installing an AM2+ CPU on this motherboard?  Would the computer likely:

- Not even POST
- POST but not boot
- Boot but be lacking some important features
- Work with a few purely cosmetic issues

or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the one instance I've (accidently) tried to put an AM2+ into an AM2 board (some ASUS) it didn't POST. Some head scratching, manual reading and a BIOS upgrade later it Just Worked (tm).